How does multiplication work with a comparison? a*(b<c)
I am a novice programmer and I am developing in PySimpleGui. I was reviewing the section on simulated tables that can be cycled through with the arrow keys.
However, there is a portion of code that, although I "deduce" what it does, I don't understand how it works.
Program: https://docs.pysimplegui.com/en/latest/cookbook/ecookbook/elements/tables/simulated-tables/
Here is the part of the code:
if event.startswith('Down'):
    r = r + 1 * (r < MAX_ROWS-1)  # I don't understand this multiplication

I understand that this helps to avoid generating an overflow error, which is why r takes a maximum of values ​​less than 4 so that in the worst case it goes from r=3 to r=4. However, assuming its behavior, I do not fully understand the operation since if r=0, the operation would result in: r = 0 + 1 * (0 < 4), r=0. I don't understand. Obviously I'm not seeing something.

The result of (r < MAX_ROWS-1) is one of the boolean values True or False. bool is a subclass of int and so True is treated as 1 and False is treated as 0 in this context.
This means that if r already reached the value of MAX_ROWS-1 you'll get r = r + 1 * 0 and r remains unchanged. If r is smaller than MAX_ROWS-1 you get r = r + 1 * 1 and r is increased by 1.

Any idea why they did 1 *?

@nocomment  They probably "optimized" if (r < MAX_ROWS-1) r = r + 1 by removing the if branching instruction, so the + 1 was already there, and they used a known trick that works for any value. It will do nothing for performance within a GUI and just makes the code less readable, but there you have it.
